# Лог с использованием log4j2

Tags: java, selenium, log4j2

**Переведено** :

Как сделать лог с использованием Log4j, когда лог метод вызывается перед тем,
как он прошёл проверку "прошёл или неудачно"

Вот пример кода и описание:

```
log.info("Какой-то текст");// Должно быть написано при условии, что method1() сработал
log.info("Какой-то текст");// Должно быть написано при условии, что method2() сработал
и т.д...
```

З.Ы. За перевод если что извините, у меня просто натянутая 4 по английскому языку :)

**Original:**

How to log with using log4j2 when log method called before the method to be checked passed/failed?

Here is a simple code and description:

```
log.info("Some text");//Should be write to console if method1() - passed
method1();
log.info("Some text");//Should be write to console if method2() - passed
method2();
etc...
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Привет, возможно поможет следующее:

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
private static String tempText;
private static boolean empty = false;

public static void step(String step) {
    if(!empty) {
       tempText = step;
       empty = true;
    }else{
       log.info("-=============== [" + tempText + "] ===============-");
       tempText = step;
    }

 }
```

Делаем таким образом, что первый метод логирования, ничего не логирует, а лишь только запоминает во временную переменную текст, а затесм если метод прошел, то выводит степ1 и т.д.